# Azure pipelines only add extra docker tag if a git tag is pushed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm building a CI pipeline within azure pipelines and am struggling with the following, I have a buildstep that is always triggered. Hence I give my image the commit hash as tag for future reference. However, I want to add the gittag name whenever this has triggered the push. Is there a way to conditionally add this tag? My current task is:

```
- task: Docker@2                                                               
  inputs:                                                                      
    containerRegistry: 'my-registry'                                           
    repository: '$(System.TeamProject)/$(Build.Repository.Name)'               
    command: 'buildAndPush'                                                    
    Dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'                                                   
    tags: |                                                                    
      $(Build.SourceVersion)                                                   
      $(Build.SourceBranchName)
```

This adds the tag, but whenever a commit to a branch was the trigger I also get a branch tag (develop / main), I'd like to prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In YAML pipeline, you can use the **`if`** expression to conditionally set a task input dynamically (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-set-a-task-input)).

With this feature, you can set different values to an input of the task in different conditions. This should be able to meet your demands.